# Find a word in a steam json and print

Tags: json, python-3.x, steam

I am trying to print the number after `quantity` in the following JSON:

```
app_data : {
    quantity: 1,
    ...
    ...
}
```

[This is the link where I am trying to print](https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198404652782/inventory/json/440/2)

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.abspath("chromedriver"), options=chrome_options)
inv = "https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198404652782/inventory/json/440/2"
with urllib.request.urlopen(inv) as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
    result = data.find('quantity')
    print(data, result)
    print(data)
```

Also tried .find() but no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json.loads()` returns a dictionary, and a dictionary does not have a `find()` method on it. Also, what the request returns is a nested dictionary, so a direct key lookup won't work. You may have to try something like what's been suggested in these earlier posts.

[Find all occurrences of a key in nested python dictionaries and lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807634/find-all-occurrences-of-a-key-in-nested-python-dictionaries-and-lists)

[How can I search for specific keys in this nested dictionary in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49662970/how-can-i-search-for-specific-keys-in-this-nested-dictionary-in-python)

Answer (score -1):

You are searching for a key, So just use a condition for it..

```
if 'quantity' in data:
  print data['quantity']
```

Comment: OP's working with a nested dictionary and 'quantity' is not one of its top-level keys.